# Firebase Web Analytics: What is App version and how to set it

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Hi I have been trying the new web analytics for my firebase projects and I see an App version user property as seen below. 
However with some research I could not figure out how to set this property or what it really means in terms of my Firebase web app, since on web there is (AFAIK) no app version config or place to set it.

Via [Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en) it says:

> The versionName (Android) or the Bundle version (iOS).

My app is a web app...

[image]

So how can I change this "app version" ?

I read a couple of help pages such as 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en
https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/9355655?hl=en&ref_topic=9353537

Comment: Why the downvotes? I simply dont get why everytime I post a firebase question I get downvotes. Is there a firebase team downvoting everything? 
I am asking a question here and I have given all the context and research

Comment: I have no idea why would someone downvote it as well - I think this question is very good, upvoted. My simple guess is that someone thought this is about Firebase Analytics for apps, then answer would be too simple.

Comment: @michalbrz yeah I get that. But somehow it gets reported strangely especially if you dont have an app version. 

I think it might just be GA trying to show a metric that doesn't exist. 

Funnily I released app version 9 (defined on npm package) and I saw 8. 
That 8 must be visitors  (so the UI is confusing) and I was lead to think that 8 was a version number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand so far that number 8 is just the visitors/events and the panel just lucks the app version info looking very confusing.

example 
[image]

So under the top app version you get the events/visits not the app version since it doesn't exist/defined.

UI could have been better

Answer (score 2):

For web apps I believe that the property is called "app_version".
Web app versions don't show up for me either in the "Top app version" view. It seems like a missing feature in Firebase Analytics.
I say this because the Typescript types for `firebaseApp.analytics().logEvent` suggests that the eventParams can have a field called `app_version`.

[image: From firebase@7.6.2]

Comment: This type def is specifically only for the event called "screen_view".  Adding "app_version" to your event params for custom events will still work, but I don't think Firebase / Google Analytics will know/care about it.

Comment: I rather set app_revision user property with current git commit's short SHA.